# What the difference between install a module with npm node console or in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm

I'm new and I need to use **node** for off-line use so, I'm trying to understand how the install modules work.

It's the same if I use `npm install express` or included it in the `package.json`?

Answer (score 2):

The way a package is installed will be the same whether you manually type `npm install express` or put it in your `package.json` and then do `npm install`.  The difference comes when you try to install your Node project elsewhere.

For example, if your code was checked into GitHub and you didn't include a `package.json` with all of the dependencies listed, then when the project was downloaded you would have to manually re-install all of the dependencies on the command line in order for it to work.  But if you had checked in a `package.json` with the code, then you could run `npm install` to install all of the dependencies at once, and not have to remember which ones were necessary.

In addition, the `package.json` allows you to specify an "approximate version" of a dependency to use.  This way if a few packages in your project share a dependency and they all specify similar "approximate versions", only one version will be installed and it will be shared between packages.  This saves some install time.

Comment: Can we create a docker image with all npm modules installed at specific location using package.json?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing actually. But you don't want to do that again and again. So you might as well put your module dependencies in your package.json